# Quick question on integration by parts

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Suppose I want to find the indefinite integral for $\frac {a(x)}{b(x)}$ where $a(x)=p(x)q(x)$, am I correct in solving it this way:
$$\begin{align}
\int \frac {a(x)}{b(x)} dx&=\frac1{b(x)}\int a(x) \ dx-\int\biggl(\frac1{b(x)}\biggr)'\biggl(\int a(x) \ dx\biggr) \ dx\\
&=\frac1{b(x)}\int p(x)q(x) \ dx-\int\biggl(\frac1{b(x)}\biggr)'\biggl(\int p(x)q(x) \ dx\biggr) \ dx\\
&=\frac1{b(x)}\biggl(p(x)\int q \ dx-\int p'(x)\Bigl(\int q(x) \ dx\Bigr) \ dx\biggr)-\int\biggl(\frac1{b(x)}\biggr)'\biggl(p(x)\int q(x) \ dx-\int p'(x)\Bigl(\int q(x) \ dx\Bigr) \ dx\biggr) \ dx
\end{align}
$$
Is this integral correct? Or are there principles I am overlooking? And also, are there other things that I should keep in mind?

Comment: If $\;b\;$ is in fact a non-constant function of $\;x\;$ then the first step is completely wrong: you can **not** take out of the integral such a term.

Comment: @DonAntonio So if I understood correctly, $$\int\frac{2x}{3x^2}dx\neq\int\frac1{3x^2}\cdot2xdx$$ ??

Comment: @JohnGlenn That is *not* what you did in your very first step...

Comment: @DonAntonio I do not nderstand what is meant by a `non-constant function`

Comment: What I meant with $\int \frac{a}{b}$ is $\int \frac{a(x)}{b(x)}$ or $\int\frac1{b(x)}\cdot a(x)$ so that's why I proceeded with the product rule.

Comment: @JohnGlenn I can't make it clearer than that. I can give you some examples, though: $\;e^x\,,\,\,x^3,\,\,\frac{3x-1}{x^4+6}\;$ , etc. All these are non-constant functions of $\;x\;$ . A constant function is $\;f(x)=k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb R\;$ . Also because of this it is not such a good idea to write $\;a\;$ instead of $\;a(x)\;$ , say.

Comment: Your very first step is $\;\int\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}dx=\frac1{b(x)}\int\ldots\;$ This is wrong **unless** $\;b(x)\;$ is a constant number.

Comment: @JohnGlenn What you mean is : You multiply $\frac{1}{b(x)}$ with the antiderivate of $a(x)$ and then differentiate $\frac{1}{b(x)}$ and so on.This can be done, but usually makes the integrand worse.

Comment: @DonAntonio Why is the first step wrong? He is applying integration by parts.

Comment: @F.A. In fact, but the notation is quite misleading.

Comment: @JohnGlenn If you actually have a product and want to apply integration by parts. $(1)$ ln(x) times a polynomial : Differntiate the ln $(2)$ a polynomial times sin(x),cos(x),$e^x$ : Differntiate the polynomial

Comment: @F.A. The notation was pretty misleading...

Comment: @DonAntonio Maybe but its not wrong he only forgot  the dx he applied integration by part two times thats all